# glOrtho influencing gluPerspective

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

so far i though glOrtho sets up a orthongonal camera while gluPerspective sets up a perspective camera.

but if i have a glOrtho call before a gluPerspective, then this also influences the position where the perspective camera is looking.

for example:

```
 gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
 gl.glOrthof(0, 1, 0, 2, -100, 100);
 GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 90, 1, 0.1f, 100.0f);

 gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
 GLU.gluLookAt(gl,  0f, 0f, -5.0f, 
                        0f, 0f, 0.0f, 
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

this will put my objects in the lower right corner. but i expected gluPerspective to override glOrtho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml):

> The matrix generated by gluPerspective is multipled by the current matrix, just as if glMultMatrix were called with the generated matrix. To load the perspective matrix onto the current matrix stack instead, precede the call to gluPerspective with a call to glLoadIdentity.

Your assumption that `gluPerspective` overrides `glOrtho` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all calls that manipulate transformations are applied relative to the current matrix. The exception are the `glLoad*` calls (`glLoadIdentity`, `glLoadMatrix`), which replace the current matrix.

The [`gluPerspective` man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) specifically documents this:

> The matrix generated by gluPerspective is multipled by the current matrix, just as if glMultMatrix were called with the generated matrix. To load the perspective matrix onto the current matrix stack instead, precede the call to gluPerspective with a call to glLoadIdentity.

In your code, `gluLookAt` should be part of the modelview matrix. You will want to precede it by:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gluLookAt(...);
```

Comment: actually it is. sorry i missed that in my original post. edited now.